# Gap between window and window sill

Tags: windows, gap, weatherstripping

After a few years I noticed there is a gap between window and window sill. It does not bring water to the indoors, but I am concerned it may bring cold air or drafts. Attached images.

Window zoomed out, gaps labeled:

[image: win0]

Zoomed in on gap 1:

[image: winclose]

Outdoor sealings and structure. Note the resin is like a flap, attached at the top only:

[image: outdoor1]

This issue is in windows at the kitchen, in bedroom, bathroom, etc, all except balcony windows and doors.

Previously last two years I put masking tape there to eliminate drafts. It was annoying, caught mold easily as there often is condensation on the inside of the window, and hard to remove after winter ended.

Is it OK to just seal such gaps with silicone? Or is something else required?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ruskes Thanks for the tip- the outdoor resin piece is like a flap, I don't know whether that's intentional or it also needs fixing? Clarified the question, please check.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this. I can't see enough in that exterior photo to understand the structure of the window. That vinyl flap doesn't look like a window component but a flashing for the brick.

Comment: Part of the problem is that vinyl windows often have weep holes or channels that must not be blocked.

Comment: @isherwood the window frame is made of a metal, probably aluminum ?

Comment: Ok, but the problem remains. I can't see enough to offer advice. Any branding?

Comment: Not seeing any branding on the window or its frame, @isherwood